# Identifying a specific network adapter

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming, ip

My application runs on a computer with multiple network adapters (between 2-4), all are connected to a different Internal Network.

I need to get a specific adapter's ip address to use in my application, the trouble is that I don't know enough information about that adapter.
the names of the adapter's are not constant, and neither is the network masking between them or the order in which they are connected (i.e index).

I also can't rely on pinging address using the adapters because as I said they are connected to differnt networks (so a specific address can be raplyed from multiple networks), and because not all adapters must be connected to the networks at all time.

What I do know about the adapters is this:

- The IP address is static for all adapters (but of course is different between the application many machines).
- The adapter I need is the computer on-board adapter.

Is there any other information\technique\dark-voodoo I can use to identify the specific adapter?

my application runs in C# -.Net 4, but as this is so critical I would use every CLI, wrapping or script language in my application to solve this.

Comment: In Device Manager network adaptes there is a location.  Not sure if 0 always means on-board.  And I don't know how to get that information in .NET.

Comment: I tried to go down that road but from what I understand the on-board adapter been the 0 index depends on the kind of motherboard in use.
and like so many other factors in my problem it is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pInvoke GetBestInterface(), and then find the interface with that index, and get his IpAddress.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetBestInterface(UInt32 DestAddr, out UInt32 BestIfIndex);

    private string GetCorrectIPAddress(string server_ip_string)
    {
        string correctIpAddress = "";

        System.Net.IPAddress server_IpAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("server_ip_string").AddressList[0];

        UInt32 ipv4AddressAsUInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(server_IpAddress.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
        UInt32 interfaceindex;

        int result = GetBestInterface(ipv4AddressAsUInt32, out interfaceindex);
        foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface nic in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = nic.GetIPProperties();
            if (ipProps.GetIPv4Properties().Index == interfaceindex)
            {
                correctIpAddress = ipProps.UnicastAddresses[0].Address.ToString();
            }
        }
        return correctIpAddress;
    }
```

Comment: From what I've read GetBestInterface retrieves the interface that has the best connection to a given address (server_ip_string in your suggestion I'm guessing).
This isn't good since the different interfaces are connected to separate & different networks.
Every given IP address can be mapped to different machine on each different networks, so all of the interfaces might have a great connection to the given address, but these are different machines.

BTW, don't spend to much time on this, it's three years old and that system has been replaced.